# Trying to remove some characters from product tags with liquid for search engine purposes with no luck

Tags: json, shopify, e-commerce, liquid

So I use tags with a low-dash before each word for filtering purposes. Now some of those tags have special search keywords that are not throwing result because user's search input don't contain the character. I'm trying to remove the the character with a for loop on the **search.elsp-tag-json.liquid** file:

```html
{% layout none %} 
{% for tag in collection.all.all_tags %}
{% assign arr = tag | remove '_' %}
{{ arr | json}}
{% endfor %}
```

I know that the search process must be occurring in the backend, but I'm not quite sure how can I strip that character before feeding the data to the server. Am I even looking at the correct file? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with liquid.

The purpose of liquid is for outputting data, there is no way to modify any of the functionality that is tied to the backend.

The only way is to update the tags from the back-end directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense. I was using code to not display the tags (I'm using them for collection filtering purposes) that contained the character, but you're right, this only calling the tags that already have a that character and doing all the work in the front end. Now, how about a js script that makes a post request to modify the tags on search function maybe in JSON format? Would that be possible without using liquid?

Comment: @Joe_fefs nope, you can't do anything to modify the search default logic from the front-end. Simply said what you are trying to do is not possible without some kind of an App.

Comment: thanks again, I'm learning web development and Shopify as we speak so I'm not entirely familiar with it, but I think I'm beginning to understand. So if I did understand, I could create a custom app that works with the backend data exclusively, right?

In terms of front end, would it be possible to feed the search term with the character and without the character so the backend does its thing? Example: user searches for "tabletops" and Shopify automatically sends "_tabletops" and "tabletops" to the back end, therefore having a match with the tags, or is this a dumb approach? Thanks!